# Using listview in fragments and making a call to dialer

Tags: android

I want to call phone dialer by an `ImageView`  and I am using `Listview` in a fragment layout what should I do?

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_appointments, container, false);
        ListView listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        imgv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imphone);
        imgv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                makeCall();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
    public void makeCall() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel" +"99986326"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Already you make calling, Tell us the problem

Comment: Check the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56816475/4364890

Comment: When i Click the phone icon the app crashes.....

Answer (score 1):

You have to change it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", "+99986326", null));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will not make call directly but open the dialer populating the number you provided. If you have to make call directly from app, then ACTION_CALL permission must be included in manifest and also it is necessary to check for permission before executing the startactivity code above.